# Implementing the Backward Nondeterministic Dawg Matching algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to implement the BNDM algorithm in my code, in order to perform a fast pattern search.

I found some code [online](http://algo.pw/algo/53/) and tried to adjust it for my use case:

[image: codeadjusted]

I think that I did something wrong while changing the values, since the algorithm takes a few minutes to finish (I was expecting it to be faster).

---

Using **std::search** takes me 30 seconds (with wildcards).
This takes me around 4-5 minutes (without wildcards).

The reason I'm casting everything to (unsigned char) is because the program crashes otherwise, since both my data and pattern hold hex values.

---

What I'd like to know is, where did I go wrong with this implementation (why is it running so slow)? and how can I include the ability to search for a pattern that contains wildcards?

---

EDIT*
The issue with speed has been solved by switching build from debug to release.
Also changing the size of the B array to 256 made it even faster.

The only issue I currently have now is how to implement a way to use wildcards using this algorithm.

Current code:

```
vector<unsigned int> get_matches(const vector<char> & data, const string & pattern) {
vector<unsigned int> matches;
//vector<char>::const_iterator walk = data.begin();

std::array<std::uint32_t, 256> B{ 0 };
int m = pattern.size();
int n = data.size();

int i, j, s, d, last;
//if (m > WORD_SIZE)
//  error("BNDM");

// Pre processing 
//memset(B, 0, ASIZE * sizeof(int));
s = 1;
for (i = m - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    B[(unsigned char)pattern[i]] |= s;
    s <<= 1;
}

// Searching phase 
j = 0;
while (j <= n - m) {
    i = m - 1; last = m;
    d = ~0;
    while (i >= 0 && d != 0) {
        d &= B[(unsigned char)data[j + i]];
        i--;
        if (d != 0) {
            if (i >= 0)
                last = i + 1;
            else
                matches.emplace_back(j);
        }
        d <<= 1;
    }
    j += last;
}
return matches;
}
```

Comment: Post the code not photos of it made with your mobile phone.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Öö Tiib I edited in the code, if that helps

Comment: *why is it running so slow* -- You need to post the compiler flags you used to build your code.  If you're running an unoptimized or "debug" build, then any timing results you're getting are meaningless.  Also, if you coded any sort of nested loops (and you did do this), you run the danger of having an `O(n^2)`  complexity, which almost always is a reason for slowness.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie oh wow... this is awkward.. Switching the build to Release fixed the slow search (now taking 4 seconds, as opposed to 4-5 minutes).
That solves one of my questions, but how do I implement the ability to search for a pattern with wildcards using this algorithm?

Comment: @Official229 -- I think that's more of an algorithm question and not one necessarily C++ related.  Better to address that issue with a new question.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie alright, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Is https://github.com/google/re2 an option? The algorithms are complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B` is not big enough -- it is indexed by the bytes in the pattern so it must have 256 elements (assuming an 8-bit byte architecture.) But you define it as having `pattern.size()` elements,  which is a much smaller number.

As a consequence, you are using memory outside of B's allocation, which is Undefined Behaviour.

I suggest you use [`std::array<std::uint32_t, 256>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), since you don't ever need to resize `B`. (Or even better, `std::array<std::uint32_t, std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()+1>`).

---

I'm not an expert on this particular search algorithm, but the preprocessing step appears to set bit `p` in element `c` of `B` if the character `c` matches pattern element `p`. Since a wildcard pattern element can match any character, it seems reasonable that every element of `B` should have the bits corresponding to wildcard characters set. In other words, instead of initialising every element of `B` to 0, initialise them to the mask of wildcard positions in the pattern.

I don't know if that is sufficient to get the algorithm to work with wildcards, but it could be worth a try.

Comment: I replaced the `vector B` with your `array B`, which has made the search even faster. This has gotten rid of my speed problem even more. But one of my bigger issues still remains. How do I implement the ability to search for a pattern that contains wildcards using this algorithm?

Comment: @Official229: I added a possible answer to your second question, although on the whole it is better to ask two (different) questions when you have two questions to ask.